# calculate sum of integers from a file using structure pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

```
struct DATA
{
int *pData;
int nSize;
int nSum;
int nMax;
int nMin;
float fMean;
};

struct DATA ReadDataFile(const char *pFileName);

int main(void)
{
DATA stData = ReadDataFile ("data.txt");
printf("We read %d numbers\n", stData.nSum);
printf("SUM: %d\nMEAN: %f\nMAX: %d\nMIN: %d\n",
(float)stData.nSum / stData.nSize, stData.nMax, stData.nMin); return 0;
}
```

How to assign values from `data.txt` to `*pData` and calculate `nSum`?
I have done it by storing values into array. But unable to assign and complete using pointer?

i did using arrays as below.

```
if (infile.is_open())
    {
            while (infile.good())
            {
                    infile.getline(cNum, 256, ' ');
                    arrays[count]= atoi(cNum) ;
                    ++count ;
            }
            infile.close();
            min = arrays[0];
            max = arrays[0];
            for(int j=0; j<count; j++)
            {
                if(min > arrays[j])
                    min = arrays[j];
                if(max < arrays[j])
                    max = arrays[j];
                sum = sum + arrays[j];
            }
            mean = sum/count;
            cout<<"Sum= "<<sum<<"; Min= "<<min<<"; Max= "<<max<<"; Mean= "<<mean<<"\n";
    }
```

But how use structure to do the same??

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: You don't appear to have anything called `pData`.

Comment: how can i store integer values from data.txt and use them for sum? @JonathanPotter

Answer (score 1):

`pData` should be your dynamically allocated array.
Get the number of elements of your file and allocate that much memory :

```
your_struct.pData = new int[your_struct.nSize];
```

Then you can fill it with `int` values in your file and use the array to calculate sum, max, min and mean.

And don't forget to `delete[] your_struc.pData` when you're done with it.